# R: apply operations to vectors with different suffixes

Tags: r

I have to perform some simple operations upon few vectors and rows.

Assume that I have a database such as:

```
observation      outcome_1_a   outcome_2_a   outcome_1_b   outcome_2_b choice_a choice_b 
1                41            34            56            19          1        1 
2                32            78            43            6           2        1
3                39            19            18            55          1        2
```

For each observation, outcome_1 and outcome_2 are the two possible outcomes, choice is the outcome chosen and the prefix _i, with i = a,b, indicates the number of times the *situation* is repeated.

If I want to create variables storing the highest outcome for each *situation* (a,b), hence:

```
max.a <- pmax(data$outcome_1_a, data$outcome_2_a)
max.b <- pmax(data$outcome_1_b, data$outcome_2_b)
```

Similarly, if I want to create variables storing the values chosen in each *situation*, I can do:

```
choice.a <- ifelse(data$choice_a == "1", data$outcome_1_a, data$outcome_1_b)
choice.b <- ifelse(data$choice_b == "1", data$outcome_2_a, data$outcome_2_b)
```

Finally, If I'd like to compute the mean by row of the *situations* a and b, I can do:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, .(Mean = rowMeans(.SD)), by = observation, .SDcols = c("outcome_1_a","outcome_2_a", "outcome_1_b", "outcome_2_b")]
```

Now, all of these work just fine. However, I was wondering if such operations can be done in a more efficient way.

In the example there are only few *situations*, but, if in the future I'll have to deal with, let's say, 15 or more different situations (a,b,c,d,...,), writing such operations might be annoying.

Is there a way to automate such process based on the different prefixes and/or suffixes of the variables?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can select columns with some regex. For example, to get your `max.a` value.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)
data[, do.call(pmax, .SD), .SDcols = names(data) %like% "\\d+_a$"]

[1] 41 78 39
```

Alternatively, you could select your columns with some regex outside of the `data.table`. Lots of ways to go about this.

Similar application to your last command.

```
data[, 
     .(Mean = rowMeans(.SD)), 
     by = observation, 
     .SDcols = names(data) %like% "^outcome"]
   observation  Mean
1:           1 37.50
2:           2 39.75
3:           3 32.75
```

For `choice.a`, how would you choose between b, c, d, e etc?

Comment: Thank you Eric. Your code works brilliantly in the `RowMeans` case. Yet (excuse me if I got anything working), in case of pair max by column does not automate the process: that is, writing `data[, do.call(pmax, .SD), .SDcols = names(data) %like% "\\d+_a$"]` gives me the same output as `pmax(data$outcome_1_a, data$outcome_2_a)`. I still have to change the letter manually in the `SDcols` argument

Answer (score 1):

For instance:

```
outcome_1_a outcome_2_a outcome_1_b outcome_2_b outcome_1_c outcome_2_c outcome_1_d outcome_2_d outcome_1_e outcome_2_e choice_a choice_b choice_c choice_d choice_e
        <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1          12          85          32          28          91          42          32          96          27          29        2        1        1        1        1
2          17          22          84          53          11          69          16          66          11          41        1        2        2        1        1
3          92          98          76          83          18          27          21          51          92          41        1        1        1        1        2
4          63          49          61          64         100          28          43          51          22          94        1        2        1        1        1
```

Define an index variable that will help you go through the loops:

```
seqmax <- seq(1, 10, by = 2)
```

`seqmax` is a `1 3 5 7 9`. The reason being is that there are 5 letters `"a" "b" "c" "d" "e"`. So this sequence will help you to pattern the loop. This can be automated for the max number of letters, just find the column index for the last column before `choice_a`. Then you can do `seq(1, grep(names(data), pattern = "choice_a") - 1, by = 2)`. The `by = 2` argument can be adjusted for the number of columns by letter.

I use `lapply` with `<<-` to assing the new column to `data`.

```
lapply(c(1:5), function(x){

  data[, paste0("max.", letters[x])] <<- apply(data[, c(seqmax[x], seqmax[x] + 1)], 1, max)

  data[, paste0("choice.", letters[x])] <<- ifelse(
    data[, grep(names(data), pattern = paste0("choice_", letters[x]), value = T)] == 1,
  data[, seqmax[x]], data[, seqmax[x] + 1])

  data[, paste0("mean.", letters[x])] <<- rowMeans(
    data[, grep(names(data), pattern = paste0("outcome_\\d+_", letters[x]), value = T)])

})
```